# How to correctly include additional entity objects in this method

Tags: c#

C# newb here with an inherited solution.

Here is the method I am working with:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<long, string>> IndexDocumentsAsync(TaskSource source, List<RawCaptureEntity> captures, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var documents = new List<DocumentAction>();

    var results = new Dictionary<long, string>();
    foreach (var capture in captures)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var text = TruncateText(CleanseText(capture.Text));
        var entities = await GetEntities(text);
        if ((source.MedWLSSource & 1) == 1)
        {
            var documentAction = GetWlsDocumentAction(source, capture, text, entities);
            if (documentAction == null)
            {
                results.Add(capture.CaptureId, $"Status [{(int)capture.Status} - {capture.Status.ToString()}] is not supported for indexing.");
            }
            else
            {
                documents.Add(documentAction);
            }
        }

        if ((source.MedWLSSource & 2) == 2)
        {
            var documentAction = GetMedDocumentAction(source, capture, text, entities);
            if (documentAction == null)
            {
                if (!results.ContainsKey(capture.CaptureId))
                {
                    results.Add(capture.CaptureId, $"Status [{(int)capture.Status} - {capture.Status.ToString()}] is not supported for indexing.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                documents.Add(documentAction);
            }
        }
    }

    var indexResults = await indexDb.BulkOperationAsync(documents);
    foreach (var result in indexResults)
    {
        var key = documents[result.Key].Document.CaptureId;
        if (!results.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            results.Add(key, result.Value);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:  regarding the lines

```
 var text = TruncateText(CleanseText(capture.Text));
 var entities = await GetEntities(text);
```

Please note that `Text` (note it's capitalized) in `capture.Text` is a database field called "Text."  That right there is enough to cause a bit of confusion because in this code, "text" does NOT necessarily equal "Text."

What this `GetEntities` method does is instructs our entity extractor to extract entities from our database field called `Text` and pass it in to the new `Dictionary` as an object called `entities` seen in this method:

```
private DocumentAction GetSearchDocumentAction(TaskSource source, RawCaptureEntity capture, string text, object[] entities)
{
    var documentAction = GetDocumentAction(source, capture, indexSettings.WLS);

    documentAction.Document.Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"address", CleanseText(capture.Region) },
        {"remarks", CleanseText(capture.Remarks) },
        {"text", text },
        {"weight", CleanseText(capture.Weight)},
        { "entities", entities}
    };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(capture.IndividualName))
    {
        documentAction.Document.Attributes.Add("individualName", CleanseText(capture.IndividualName));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(capture.EntityName))
    {
        documentAction.Document.Attributes.Add("entityName", CleanseText(capture.EntityName));
    }

    return documentAction;
}
```

I have two other database fields that I need to run through the entity extractor and have passed to that `entities` list.  Those fields are called `IndividualName` and `EntityName`.  As a beginner, I want to make sure I add this code correctly and include what needs to be included, and not include what doesn't need to be. I'm in essence trying to understand how much code needs to be repeated to accomplish this.

My first stab at this looked like this:

```
var documents = new List<DocumentAction>();

var results = new Dictionary<long, string>();
foreach (var capture in captures)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    var text = TruncateText(CleanseText(capture.Text));        
    var iname = TruncateText(CleanseText(capture.IndividualName));
    var ename = TruncateText(CleanseText(capture.EntityName));
    var entities = await GetEntities(text,iname,ename);
    //...
}
```

but I was immediately met with intellisense telling me `no overload for method GetEntities takes 3 arguments.`

**EDIT 1**: I don't think the `GetEntities` method is meant to execute on 3 objects simultaneously anyway. So I want to pass them each separately, but all within the `IndexDocumentsAsync` method and to build a combined object called `entities`.
**END EDIT 1**

Will I need 3 complete separate code blocks for each of the database fields I'm trying to do extraction on?

I figured before I got way too deep into this rabbit hole, I needed to come here for guidance.  In addition to needing to know how I can get that `entities` variable to include all data extracted from `Text`, `IndividualName` and `EntityName`, I also want to make sure I'm not missing any references to `iname` and `ename` in the rest of the `IndexDocumentAsync` method.

Finally, if the code is all correct in the `IndexDocumentAsync` method, I would assume that I would not need to add anything to the `Dictionary` in the `GetSearchDocumentAction` method as the `entities` object in there will contain all information extracted from all three database fields.

Post-editing is highly welcomed if any nomenclature is being used incorrectly. I appreciate everyone's help.

**EDIT 2:**

Adding the code for `GetEntities` per suggestion:

```
       private async Task<object[]> GetEntities(string text)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(
                extractionUrl,
                new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { content = text, options = new { linkEntities = false } }), null, "application/json"));

            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var entities = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body);
                var names = entities.SelectTokens("$.entities[*]");

                var list = new List<object>();
                foreach (var name in names)
                {
                    var type = name.SelectToken("$.type").ToString();
                    if (type == "PERSON"
                        || type == "ORGANIZATION")
                    {
                        list.Add(new { name = name.SelectToken("$.mention").ToString() });
                    }
                }
                return list.ToArray();
            }
            if((body.Contains("Language")
                && body.Contains("not supported"))
                || (body.Contains("License check failed for endpoint: /entities, language:")))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var error = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body);
            throw new Exception(error.SelectToken("$.message").ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**END EDIT 2:**

**EDIT 3:**  I took a stab at this on my own last night, and did so by trying to create 3 separate objects - this is the code I put together:

```
 public async Task<Dictionary<long, string>> IndexDocumentsAsync(TaskSource source, List<RawCaptureEntity> captures, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var documents = new List<DocumentAction>();

            var results = new Dictionary<long, string>();
            foreach (var capture in captures)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                var text = TruncateText(CleanseText(capture.Text));
                var entities = await GetEntities(text);
                var iname = TruncateText(CleanseText(capture.IndividualName));
                var entitiesIname = await GetEntities(iname);
                var ename = TruncateText(CleanseText(capture.EntityName));
                var entitiesEname = await GetEntities(ename);
                if ((source.MedWLSSource & 1) == 1)
                {
                    var documentAction = GetWlsDocumentAction(source, capture, text, entities, entitiesIname, entitiesEname);
                    if (documentAction == null)
                    {
                        results.Add(capture.CaptureId, $"Status [{(int)capture.Status} - {capture.Status.ToString()}] is not supported for indexing.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        documents.Add(documentAction);
                    }
                }

                if ((source.MedWLSSource & 2) == 2)
                {
                    var documentAction = GetMedDocumentAction(source, capture, text, entities);
                    if (documentAction == null)
                    {
                        if (!results.ContainsKey(capture.CaptureId))
                        {
                            results.Add(capture.CaptureId, $"Status [{(int)capture.Status} - {capture.Status.ToString()}] is not supported for indexing.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        documents.Add(documentAction);
                    }
                }
            }

            var indexResults = await indexDb.BulkOperationAsync(documents);
            foreach (var result in indexResults)
            {
                var key = documents[result.Key].Document.CaptureId;
                if (!results.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    results.Add(key, result.Value);
                }
            }

            return results;
        }
```

And then revised the `GetWlsDocumentAction` and `GetMedDocumentAction` methods to look like this:

```
private DocumentAction GetWlsDocumentAction(TaskSource source, RawCaptureEntity capture, string text, object[] entities, object[] entitiesIndName, object[] entitiesEntName)
{
    var documentAction = GetDocumentAction(source, capture, indexSettings.WLS);

    documentAction.Document.Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"address", CleanseText(capture.Region) },
        {"remarks", CleanseText(capture.Remarks) },
        {"text", text },
        {"weight", CleanseText(capture.Weight)},
        {"entities", entities}
        {"entitiesIndName", entitiesIname},
        {"entitiesEntName", entitiesEname}
    };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(capture.IndividualName))
    {
        documentAction.Document.Attributes.Add("individualName", CleanseText(capture.IndividualName));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(capture.EntityName))
    {
        documentAction.Document.Attributes.Add("entityName", CleanseText(capture.EntityName));
    }

    return documentAction;
}
```

Finally, I added the two fields entitesIndName and entitiesEntName to my index to ensure there were fields to receive the information.

Although VS compiled everything without error, my code did not work.  The error message thrown upon the service trying to process the first record was:

```
{"Exception":"OPERATION=Index;EXCEPTION=A task was canceled.;PAYLOAD=11439;STACKTRACE=   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at 
Cantrel.Sources.Persistence.Repositories.CaptureIndexRepository.<GetEntities>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at 
Cantrel.Sources.Persistence.Repositories.CaptureIndexRepository.<IndexDocumentsAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Cantrel.Services.Sources.Indexer.CaptureIndexer.<IndexSource>d__8.MoveNext()","Id":"8cefc158-a8cd-489e-acd4-a70c1047755f","Content":null}
```

I"m now going to examine @sjb-sjb answer.

**END EDIT 3.**

**EDIT #4:**

After examining how our index will ingest this information, I absolutely am going to need two additional objects in the pattern of the entities object.  If said objects were to be called entitesIname and entitiesEname, how would the answer provided by @sjb-sjb be revised?

**END EDIT #4**

Comment: Can you narrow down the question to what exactly are you asking? As for the error you're getting, you're trying to pass 3 parameters to the `GetEntities()` method which apparently doesn't take three parameters.

Comment: Are you editing the first method to include other criteria for loading entities?  Or are you trying to do something similar to the first method?  Either way, I think we would need to see the code for GetEntities.  Looks like you need to change this method to accept a list of column names rather than just one, but it's such a generic name that it kind of doesn't make sense.  Is Entities a single table?  are there only one type of entity in your database?  GetEntities(columnName) doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Sach, you're right, it's not fully clear what I'm asking.  Whereas the 'Text' database field is passed as an argument for `GetEntities` - I need to do the same thing for two other database fields, and do so within the `IndexDocumentAsync` method.  See also my next response to @William Prevett...

Comment: @WilliamPrevett edited my post to include the code for `GetEntities`  I don't think the intent of the original developer was to modify anything in the `GetEntities` code.  Therefore, I think what I need to understand how to do is pass those other two database fields to `GetEntities` as two additional steps in the `IndexDocumentAsync` method, rather than trying to pass all 3 in at the same time.

Comment: It looks like your `GetEntities` is in fact doing a POST to a web service, which then sends back JSON of the entities. We'd need to know how the service works with the database to get the entities based on the arguments it receives... I think this is getting pretty deep into the weeds here for a few volunteers on a website to provide guidance. Is there no one else that knows the code that can help?

Comment: @HereticMonkey sure that definitely makes sense. and yes you're correct about `GetEntities` calling our Entity Extractor service.  No one else in my camp is familiar with this code unfortunately.  I'm certainly willing to pay someone to help me, if anyone can point me to such a person/service.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really a door we want to open on Stack Overflow ( [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) is a different thing, but that's geared toward employment rather than freelance). I'd do a search for "programmers for hire" on the internet.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok.  Well I'm going to leave this thread open and come back and post the answer after I've worked it out with someone, in hopes that it might one day help someone.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: I would have to agree with @HereticMonkey.  We would have to see how the web api handles the content in your serialized data, as well as what that serialized data actually looks like in your first example.  could be a bit much for a question here.  Maybe you can investigate it more and ask more specific questions for things that you don't understand along the way

Comment: @WilliamPrevett understood.  I will do that. Thanks.

Comment: @Stpete111 i will be willing to investigate further with you

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you could simply do GetEntities three times and append the entities into a list. However the subsequent code uses the text in conjunction with the entities. It is not obvious whether or not you can concatenate the three text fields to match the concatenated lists of entities.

That being the case, discretion is the better part of valor: one should iterate over the three text fields. The three fields can be represented by functions from RawCaptureEntity to string:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<long, string>> IndexDocumentsAsync(TaskSource source, List<RawCaptureEntity> captures, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var documents = new List<DocumentAction>();
    var results = new Dictionary<long, string>();

    foreach (var capture in captures) {
        var fields = new Func<RawCaptureEntity,string>[] { rce => rce.Text, rce => rce.IndividualName, rce => rce.EntityName };
        foreach (Func<RawCaptureEntity,string> field in fields) {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var text = TruncateText(CleanseText(field(capture)));
            var entities = await GetEntities(text));
            if ((source.MedWLSSource & 1) == 1) {
                var documentAction = GetWlsDocumentAction(source, capture, text, entities);
                if (documentAction == null) {
                    results.Add(capture.CaptureId, $"Status [{(int)capture.Status} - {capture.Status.ToString()}] is not supported for indexing.");
                } else {
                    documents.Add(documentAction);
                }
            }

            if ((source.MedWLSSource & 2) == 2) {
                var documentAction = GetMedDocumentAction(source, capture, text, entities);
                if (documentAction == null) {
                    if (!results.ContainsKey(capture.CaptureId)) {
                        results.Add(capture.CaptureId, $"Status [{(int)capture.Status} - {capture.Status.ToString()}] is not supported for indexing.");
                    }
                } else {
                    documents.Add(documentAction);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var indexResults = await indexDb.BulkOperationAsync(documents);
    foreach (var result in indexResults) {
        var key = documents[result.Key].Document.CaptureId;
        if (!results.ContainsKey(key)) {
            results.Add(key, result.Value);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

As a general comment, one should only use 'var' if it is obvious from the right-hand side what the type is. Whoever wrote the original code did not follow that advice, making it a bit harder to read.

Comment: Please see my Edit 3 for further information.  Your answer looks interesting and I'd like to give it a try.  Just want to make sure that you still agree that your code is still a potential solution after you read my edit #3.

Comment: It seems your solution would allow me to put the contents of all 3 database fields into the same entities object. But I don't know that this would work based on how our ElasticSearch index is set up.

Comment: Well … I did not try to unravel the exact cause of the exception you received but broadly I would say that your proposed solution does not work because, even though you are parsing the three text fields, you are only passing in the one string (in the local variable named "text") rather than all three of them corresponding to the three object arrays returned by the three calls to GetEntities. In addition you did not pass either the two extra strings or the two extra object arrays into the GetMedDocument function.

Comment: While one might be able to make it work by adding additional parameters to GetWlsDocumentAction and GetMedDocumentAction, that is really not the right approach from a software point of view. There are a lot of reasons to think that, for example (a) you are changing more functions and creating a bigger software change -- it could impact, for example, any other uses of these functions (b) depending on how these two methods are designed, you might end up passing the arguments into additional subroutines (c) rather unaesthetic to have multiple arguments carrying the same information; etc.

Comment: Concerning your comment that the solution "would allow me to put the contents of all 3 database fields into the same entities object": it seems that you are confusing variables (such as the one named "entities", of type object[] and the other one named "text" having string type) with the values that are stored in them. A variable can contain different values at different times. Each time through the inner loop in the solution, the "entities" and "text" variables contains a different value than they did on the previous iteration.

Comment: The various lambda expressions, such as rce => rce.IndividualName, are shorthand for functions. The corresponding hardcoded function might be something like:   string GetIndividualName( RawCaptureEntity rce) { return rce.IndividualName; }

Comment: Lambda expressions, however, can be stored in variables (such as the "fields" variable whose type is an array of Func delegates). This enables us to iterate over them conveniently using the foreach statement.

Comment: Thank you for all your detailed explanations.  Please give me a little time to implement and test your code and I will definitely mark it as the answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I think I am close, and I want to mark your answer, but I have one more question - I think it's best to move it to a chat at this point.  Would you be able to join me in a chat so we can close this out and I can mark your answer?

Comment: It would be nice, and if I were a paid support person I might, but I am so busy with all the obligations in my life that it would be hard even to figure out a time to meet. So I would suggest that you post your question here, maybe as an edit on your original post.

Comment: Understood.  Please see Edit #4.  Once I figure this out, we are definitely done here!

Comment: Really, the names of the variables don't matter to the logic. You would have to tell me a lot more about the situation for me to say anything about whether it would or would not work or any workarounds. I would point out however that the entities from the three text sources are put onto separate documents. Since BulkOperationAsync can handle at least two documents, it would be surprising if it couldn't handle more than two. Given that, I don't see any obvious problems.

Comment: Unless you're saying that all three sets of entities need to be attached to the same document. In that case what about the text, wouldn't you need to join those together as well? If so then you have to understand the format of the text.

Comment: Yes, exactly, all three entities need to be attached to the same document, separately.  See the code block in my original post that refers to `GetWlsDocumentAction` (the 7th code block in the post).  In order to properly  populate our index, the document has to have these three fields as separate.

Comment: I think I've done all that can really be done from a distance.

Comment: I understand.  Thank you for your assistance and time.